# Non-functioning elsif loop in perl

Tags: perl, awk, sed

This Perl program takes an *.mdp file as input and generates copies of that file with changes to `init_lambda` and `foreign_Lambda`.

Lambda varies from `0` to `1`. The parameter `foreign lambda` contains two values depending on the spacing, e.g. if lambda = 0.1 and spacing is 0.05 then foreign lambda values would be 0.05 and 0.1

But I want to print values of `foreign lambda` at `Lower_Lambda` and `Higher_Lambda` differently. I used a conditional statement but I couldn't understand why the second `elsif` condition, which says `elsif ($i == $Higher_Lambda)` is not being executed.

If I can achieve this using sed or awk, please suggest that too

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

# opens a generic .mdp file and replaces the values of
# 'init_lambda' and 'foreign_lambda' values at increments
# of by spacing

my $Lower_Lambda  = 0.1;
my $Higher_Lambda = 0.2;
my $Count         = 5;
my $init_spacing  = 0.05;

unless ( @ARGV ) {
    die "Usage: $0 input.mdp\n";
}

my $difference = $Higher_Lambda - $Lower_Lambda;
my $spacing    = $difference / $Count;
my $mdp        = $ARGV[0];
my @temp       = split( '\.', $mdp );
my $base       = $temp[0];

open( IN, "<$mdp" );
my @in = <IN>;
close( IN );

for ( my $i = $Lower_Lambda ; $i < $Higher_Lambda ; $i += $spacing ) {

    my $filename = "${base}_${i}.mdp";
    open( OUT, ">$filename" );

    foreach $_ ( @in ) {

        unless ( ( $_ =~ /^init_lambda/ ) || ( $_ =~ /^foreign_lambda/ ) ) {
            print OUT $_;
        }

        if ( $_ =~ /^init_lambda\s*=/ ) {

            if ( $i < 1 ) {
                printf OUT "%s %0.3f\n", $&, $i;
            }
            else {
                printf OUT "%s %.3f\n", $&, $i;
            }
        }

        if ( $_ =~ /^foreign_lambda\s*=/ ) {

            if ( $i < 1 ) {

                if ( $i == 0 ) {
                    printf OUT "%s %0.3f\n", $&, ( $i + $spacing );

                    print "I am in 0";
                }
                elsif ( $i == $lower_lambda ) {

                    printf OUT "%s %0.3f %0.3f\n", $&, $i - $init_spacing,
                      ( $i + $spacing );
                    print "I am not there";
                }
                elsif ( $i == $Higher_Lambda ) {

                    printf OUT "%s %0.3f %0.3f\n", $&, $i - $spacing,
                      $i + $init_spacing;
                    print "I am here bro";
                }
                else {

                    printf OUT "%s %0.3f %0.3f\n", $&, ( $i - $spacing ),
                      ( $i + $spacing );

                }
            }
            else {
                printf OUT "%s %0.3f\n", $&, ( $i - $spacing );
            }
        }
    }

    close( OUT );

}

exit;
```

---

#### input file

```
 energygrps               = W WF Protein DPPC 
 ; Neighborsearching and short-range nonbonded interactions
 nstlist                  = 10
 ns_type                  = grid
 pbc                      = xyz
 rlist                    = 1.3
 ; Electrostatics
 coulombtype              = shift
 rcoulomb                 = 1.2
 vdw-type                 = shift
 rvdw-switch              = 0.9

 tau_t                    = 1.0; 1.0 1.0
 ref_t                    = 300; 300 300
 ; Pressure coupling is on for NPT
 Pcoupl                   = Berendsen ; Parrinello-Rahman 
 Pcoupltype               = semiisotropic
 tau_p                    = 1.1 1.1
 compressibility          = 1e-05 1e-05
 ref_p                    = 1.0 1.0
 ; Free energy control stuff
 free_energy              = yes
 init_lambda              = 0.0
 delta_lambda             = 0
 foreign_lambda           = 0.05
 sc-alpha                 = 1.3
 sc-power                 = 1.0
 sc-sigma                 = 0.47 
 couple-moltype           = Protein  ; name of moleculetype to decouple
 couple-lambda0           = vdw-q      ; only van der Waals interactions
 couple-lambda1           = none     ; turn off everything, in this  
 vdW
 couple-intramol          = yes
 nstdhdl                  = 10
 ; Do not generate velocities
 gen_vel                  = no 
 ; options for bonds
 constraints              = h-bonds  ; we only have C-H bonds here
 ; Type of constraint algorithm
 constraint-algorithm     = lincs
 ; Constrain the starting configuration
 ; since we are continuing from NPT
 continuation             = yes  
 lincs-order              = 12
 ld_seed                   =-1
```

Comment: Format your code in a readable way.

Comment: I guess it is fine now ?

Comment: @VikasDubey: Your changes prevented it from compiling. I've rolled back to my last edit

Comment: Can you edit the question to *only* focus on the broken part? I don't want to have to dig to find this "non-functioning elsif"

Comment: Post the expected output to go with your sample input. Can't you come up with a briefer example, though, so we don't have to try to read and understand so much input data? Might encourage a few more people (e.g. me!) to try to help you if you can demonstrate your problem with 10 lines or less of input instead of 50 or whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't follow your logic of what gets preinted out at all, but it's very likely that your problem is to do with comparing floatin-point values for equality, whcih you should *never* do because of the limited precision of floating-point representation

Instead you should use an *integer* counter, and calculate the lambda value from that. In my code below I have iterated `$i` from 0 to `$count`, and then calculated the corresponding `$lambda` using

```
my $lambda = $lower_lambda + $i * $difference / $count;
```

Then you can compare `$i` against 0 and `$count` to check whether you're on the first or the last step

I have no way of knowing whether the range is right (should `$i` stop at `$count` or `$count-1`?) but that calculation is certainly correct

I'm concerned about your tests `$i== 0` and `$i < 1` as they will almost certainly fail too, but I can't see what you're trying to do. The first can only occur if `$lower_lambda` is negative or zero, and `$upper_lambda` is positive or zero, which seems unlikely. I suspect these tests are superfluous, and may be attempts to get your code working?

And *please* don't use capital letters for your lexical variables: they are reserved for global identifiers like package names, and using them for your ordinary variables could get you hopelessly confused

This code runs and creates the sequence of files correctly, but you should check the contents carefully

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

our @ARGV = 'Lower_Lambda.mdp';

die "Usage: $0 input.mdp\n" unless @ARGV;

my $mdp = $ARGV[0];

my $lower_lambda  = 0.1;
my $higher_lambda = 0.2;
my $count         = 5;
my $init_spacing  = 0.05;

my $difference = $higher_lambda - $lower_lambda;
my $spacing    = $difference / $count;

for my $i ( 0 .. $count ) {

    my $lambda = $lower_lambda + $i * $difference / $count;

    my $filename = $mdp =~ s/.*\.\K/sprintf '_%0.3f', $lambda/er;    #/

    open my $in_fh,  '<', $mdp;
    open my $out_fh, '>', $filename;

    while ( <$in_fh> ) {

        if ( /^(init_lambda\s*=\s*)/ ) {

            my $label = $1;

            printf $out_fh $label . "%0.3f\n",
                $lambda;
        }
        elsif ( /^(foreign_lambda\s*=\s*)/ ) {

            my $label = $1;

            if ( $lambda >= 1 ) {
                printf $out_fh $label . "%0.3f\n",
                    $lambda - $spacing;
            }
            elsif ( $lambda == 0 ) {
                printf $out_fh $label . "%0.3f\n",
                    $lambda + $spacing;
            }
            elsif ( $i == 0 ) {
                printf $out_fh $label . "%0.3f %0.3f\n",
                  $lambda - $init_spacing,
                  $lambda + $spacing;
            }
            elsif ( $i == $count ) {
                printf $out_fh $label . "%0.3f %0.3f\n",
                  $lambda - $spacing,
                  $lambda + $init_spacing;
            }
            else {
                printf $out_fh $label . "%0.3f %0.3f\n",
                  $lambda - $spacing,
                  $lambda + $spacing;
            }

        }
        else {
            print $out_fh $_;
        }
    }

    close $out_fh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your last question who 's not duplicate

```
if(LAMBDA == 0.95  || ( LAMBDA > 0.96 && LAMBDA <1.01  ))

           LAMBDA += 0.05;

    else

           LAMBDA += 0.1;
```